# Writing method for form posts a blank field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I am running rails 3.2

I have created a nested form (requests > tags) with coffeescript handling the addition of new tags.

Everything works with the exception of the form posting a blank tag.name

I am trying to write a method to delete the blank field before the form posts. I realize this may be the wrong approach, but I am still a beginner:

requests_controller.rb

```
  def create
        @request = current_user.requests.build(params[:request])
        @tag = Tag.new
        if @tag.name.blank?
          destroy_blank
        end

    respond_to do |format|
      if @request.save
        format.html  { redirect_to(@request,
                      :notice => 'Request was successfully created.') }
        format.json  { render :json => @request,
                      :status => :created, :location => @request }
      else
        format.html  { render :action => "new" }
        format.json  { render :json => @request.errors,
                      :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

request.rb

```
 def destroy_blank
    blank = @tag.name
    blank.delete
 end
```

I hope that's clear. If not let me know and I will include more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't stop blank tags from coming in, you can create a before_create filter in the model to skip saving blank tags. Leave the controller clean and simple.

Good luck!